# Why doesn't qmake add "QT += widgets" to *.pro files automatically?

Tags: qt

I am trying to build a simple "Hello World" example in QT5.

I am compiling the code using the below steps

```
qmake-qt5 -project
qmake-qt5
make
```

I am getting the below error

```
main.cpp:1:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
 #include <QApplication>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

When I read QT forums, its mentioned to add "QT += widgets" to the *.pro file. After doing this the code is compiled.

**Question:** Why do I need to add "QT += widgets" to the *.pro file manually ? Why doesn't qmake do it automatically ?

Note: I am using Ubuntu

***Code***

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello Qt!");
    label->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Qt still lacks a glass sphere to know which modules you want to use...

Comment: In a Qt Quick project, adding "widgets" would be unnecessary overhead. In a widgets project, adding "quick" would be unnecessary overhead. Thus qmake let's the user decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [QT variable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt) in the .pro file is used to specify the modules which are used in the project.
And as the [qmake manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt) mentions:

> By default, QT contains both core and gui, ensuring that standard GUI applications can be built without further configuration.

The [Qt Widgets module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html) is not linked by default and has thus to be specified in the .pro file with `QT += widgets`.